# after kill application and start , it runs in background

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

Hi i wrote simple script as .bat file, and if i run this using windows scheduler , it kill the application and restart , but after that application runs in background as a proces, what shoud i do to see it in my screen?

taskkill /F /IM program7.exe
start D:\AIMR\CS\program.exe

---

if u run manualy that it works, but if i run this script using task scheduler then it works as a bacground, what to do to see it as a foreground?

Comment: You might have better luck at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the command syntax is correct - no delimiter between taskkill and start?